# locally merging branch not resolving pull request on github

Tags: git, github

I have a pull request on github. The request has been approved but cannot be merged automatically. I merged the branch locally on the command line so that I could resolve the merge conflicts. How do I then resolve the original pull request? This entire process seems wrong to me. What should be proper workflow be so that github is aware of what I am doing?

Comment: Just push the branch in which you merged?

Comment: Did you push after merging? Otherwise how would GitHub know what happened?

Comment: Also please be a lot clearer about what you did; "merged the branch locally" is not very communicative. Merged what into what? _Why_ can't the request be merged automatically? Give us some actual info, don't just wave your hands at it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to push but got an error that there are remote changes not reflected locally

Comment: Then that fact needs to be in the question, doesn't it? The question should be: what you did; what you wanted / expected; what actually happened.